# Connectivity issues between SqlAlchemy/PyODBC and SQL Server running in Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a flask app that uses SQLAlchemy (v1.3.17)/PyODBC (v4.0.30) to connect to a SQL Server. In my development setup, the SQL server runs inside a Docker container using `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu` image with Docker Desktop for Mac (v2.3.0.3).

It has been working with this setup for a while now (~6 months), but for the last month or so I have been running into the following error all the time

> (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x274C (10060)

It happens intermittently, at different places in the code, and when I rerun the same code again it doesn't occur. So I don't think it is anything fundamentally wrong with my code.

10060 appears to be a connection error, but since it is able to connect initially okay, I am thinking that something failing in pyodbc when it is trying to keep the connection alive.

Has anyone else run into something similar? Is there a timeout value that I need to set in my SQL Server config? Thankfully, on the production server (which isn't running in Docker) I am not running into this problem. But it happens every couple of minutes so is very frustrating when I am debugging.

Comment: related? https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5148

Comment: did you try turning off the connection pooling ```pooling = False``` and see if the issues persist?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ed, Gin (feel free to post as answer if you would like me to endorse it). http://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5148 is the same issue and the 'pool_pre_ping' engine option suggested on there seems to have done the trick.